# Making a listview data template with XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to make a listview for my restaurant app using XAML in Xamarin that looks something like this:

[image]

The problem is I am new to XAML and can only get it to look like this:

[image]

Please assist me with this if you can :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App_Name.View.BarPage"
             xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView" >

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <flv:FlowListView x:Name="FlowListViewHk" FlowColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}"
                           SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True"
                           FlowTappedBackgroundColor="Black" IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                           ItemSelected="UpdateStatus" GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding TableNumber}"
                           FlowItemTapped="UpdateStatus"
                           FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}" FlowColumnMinWidth="220">

            <flv:FlowListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell Height="40">
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       Padding="5"
                       BackgroundColor="Red">
                            <Label Text="{Binding TBlNo}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>


            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="listx">
                        <StackLayout Margin="5" BackgroundColor="Red" >
                            <Grid x:Name="controlGrid">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="Black"
                                Text="{Binding TableNumber}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="Large"/>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding ItemName}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding OrderedQuantity}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <!--<Button Text="{Binding Status}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" Clicked="btnClicked"/>-->
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                                XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Status}"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Above is the code for my Xaml and how I am achieving the result I dont want.

Comment: we can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't show us what you're doing.  Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your input I will edit question to show Xaml code

Comment: at a glance, you've got columns with headers, just like your drawing.  What specifically are you trying to achieve that isn't working?

Comment: @Jason as you can see in the question, that code I attached produces the second screenshot and I would like to achieve something that looks more like my drawing. Please assist me if you can :)

Comment: Maybe start by simplifying the layout of your columns. You don't need to have <Grid><StackLayout><Grid> in your <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>. Replace it with just <Grid Padding="5">